# MySQL GROUP BY ignores the ORDER BY and always returns the 1st row

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have read through tons of similar questions and none is answering what is wrong with mine.

I want to select the entire row that includes the maximum value of one of the columns for each group.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    
    SELECT t1.* FROM `t1` JOIN `t2` ON t2.id=t1.raceId ORDER BY t1.points DESC

) AS new GROUP BY new.athleteId ORDER BY new.points DESC
```

This works, giving me a single row for each athlete, but the row it shows is just the earliest row in the DB, not the row with the maximum points.

The sub query alone shows all the rows in the correct order, but when I try to group them, it still takes the earliest row and ignores the ordering.

I can retrieve the maximum points for each grouping, but the rest of the row info still comes from the earliest entry.

Comment: what is the data type of points in your table ? Share sample data and table structure with queries and also share expected output. Also, no need of order by in inner query.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.5 and later also permits a nonaggregate column not named in a GROUP BY clause when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled, provided that this column is limited to a single value  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html.  I'm not sure I see where you would be limiting to a single value thus the group by is "confused"  However, it should thow an error; so I suspect you don't have ONLY_FULL GROUP BY enabled or are on a prior version which allows this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one way to achieve what you're after..

As a general rule of thumb; it's wise if you're using a "GROUP BY" to define what aggregate functions to use.  MySQL allows you to group by without aggerate functions defined but i've found this to be very confusing whiteout being very specific on what I want to aggregate on.  Maybe it's because of  my background in SQL server and oracle; which DO NOT allow you to use a group by this way...

essentially get the max points for each athlete then join back to your entire data set to limit by that athlete and points. may need to do it by race if you want athlete by race as well, i'm unsure if you want max athlete points by race, but based on the group by/order by I'm guessing not.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (SELECT athlete, max(t1.points) 
      FROM `t1` 
      INNER JOIN `t2` ON t2.id=t1.raceId
      GROUP BY athlete) new
INNER JOIN `t1` on T1.athletID = new.athletID
               and t1.points = new.points
INNER JOIN JOIN `t2` ON t2.id=t1.raceId
ORDER BY new.points DESC
```

Another way depending on version of mySQL would be to use analytic functions along with aggregate functions... but w/o version number, i'll not go into detail.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just reading through the SQL, I would assume this approach will work. I didn't think about doing it like that. I'll test it later and get back to you. In the meantime, can you explain why, using my SQL, I can get the rows I need but cannot specify a way to order the group by. Why does it select the first row entry in the DB regardless of what I do. I'm convinced there must be a simple way to do this without using subqueries.

Comment: I pretty much used this method. Tweaked it a bit and then run into a problem where people scoring 0 points had multiple rows (the same would happen if people score identical points). I sorted this out by just grouping it again so there was only 1 row per athlete. I still can't believe there isn't an easy way of doing this, i.e. ordering the group by

Comment: Order by makes no sense in your context of your inline view becuase you're not doing a top or something which the order by would have an impact upon the result sets..  So the order by does not add any value.  The outer order by ends up taking precedent.  IF you provide a sample dataset along with expected results, we may be able to work tough the duplication issue or find a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: also define what version of mySQL you're using.  if analytical functions are supported such as "over partition by" and common table expressions we may be able to assign a row number based on a desired order.  This can be done in earlier versions; it's just not as easy/elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause is meant to be used with aggeregate functions.

What is it that you are trying to achieve with the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Because my query pulls out all the athletes results from a specific set of races, 2 or more. So in the data set, I may have more than 1 result for each athlete. But I only want to include the row for each athlete where they scored the most points. So within the final dataset, the athletes have 1 unique row. That's why I'm trying to group by athlete